# Volumes of revolution

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the region $R$ bounded by the curve $y=x$, $y=1$, and the $y$-axis rotated about $x=1$.

We are rotating about a vertical axis so the cross-sectional area will be a function of $y$.

So our volume is $$V=\int_{0}^{1} A(y) \; dy$$ but my question is how do I find $A(y)$???

Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple curves like this, I would immediately translate it to revolving it around the $x$ axis. which would translate the problem to $$\pi \int_0^1 (1-(1-x)^2)dx.$$

Although, if you were forced to compute the function in terms of $y$ the general notion would be \begin{align*} A(y) &= \pi(\textbf{outer radius})^2 - \pi (\textbf{inner radius})^2 \\ &= \pi(1)^2-\pi (1-y)^2 
\\ &= \pi (1-(1-y)^2). \end{align*}

Comment: Great thank you.